# How to make use of date field in Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Nodejs and MongoDB.I have this key-value set "attendances": { : "value" } pair in my database and I am having a lot of challenges trying to figure out how to perform an aggregate operation based on the date field, with the date field being dynamic and not like so :

Employee.collection.countDocuments({"attendances.2019-08-26":"Present"},(err,data)=>{ some codes}

For instance: returning 7days worth of record.
I checked the following Docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html it wasn't particularly helpful because the doc only focused on MongoDB automatically creating a timestamp when you declare a path of type date and so When you create a user document, Mongoose will cast the value to a native JavaScript date using the Date() constructor. However in my case, I am still going to be dealing with the same document, the only thing that keeps updating is the value of the attendances which is an object---" attendances": { : "value" }

// I know this should get me 7days ago worth of data

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
// I would like to be able use date with $gte (greater or equal to ) along side a $match and $group aggregation operator
```

//Schema

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  department: String,
  origin: String,
  employDate: String,
  attendances: Object
});
module.exports= Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);
```

//Data stored in MongoDB

```
  {
        "_id": "5d6565236574b1162c349d8f",
        "name": "Sarah Gates",
        "department": "IT",
        "origin": "Texas",
        "employDate": "2019-08-27",
        "__v": 0,
        "attendances": {
            "2019-08-28": "Sick"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d6367ee5b78d30c74be90e6",
        "name": "George Washington",
        "department": "Marketing",
        "origin": "new york",
        "employDate": "2019-08-26",
        "__v": 0,
        "attendances": {
            "2019-08-26": "Present",
            "2019-08-27": "Sick"
        }
    },
```

I Want to be able to return all the records in the last 7 days that has the value of 'present' is it even possible to achieve these while retaining my database data model? I really need help here!

Comment: aggregate exec take two params , first for error and sec for success, so remove then and catch , and change exec to be  `.exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
})`  then give it a try

Comment: Thank you @Yasser Mas that absolutely cleared the error !!!!

Comment: @chrisdam your solution absolutely solved the problem! but there is one last thing I would like to ask if you don't mind...how can I modify your solution to obtain a count of all " numberofPresentAttendances"  thanks for your input, appreciated!